# How does .nuspec dependency version and packages.config package version relate to each other?

Tags: nuget

`packages.config` contains all packages used by the project. `version` attribute of `package` element requires [exact version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/packages-config) of the package.

Meanwhile `.nuspec` allows me to set the [range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/nuspec#dependencies) of allowed versions of the dependency.

If my project depends on `A` and `B`, and they in turn both depend on `C`, NuGet fetches the lowest possible version. So there is no hard fix of a version until exact version is specified in dependency `[1.0]`. Then I do net get the point of having **exact** version in `<package>` element. And it does not have `>=` semantics because if package with the exact version does not exist, package restore fails.

Contrary to that, recently introduced [PackageReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files) treats `version` as `>=`. It even supports [floating versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/dependency-resolution#floating-versions)

Answer (score 1):

They are different contexts, one is the package author specifying dependencies of his package, the other one is the user control over the package versions.

The nuspec dependency versions are basically specifying which version of the dependent package you can use. 
Basically you are saying that your package will only work if installed side-by-side with that version range of the dependant package.

On the other hand, the value in the version attribute of package is user control. Say you have Package A version 1.0, which depends on Package B range [1.0,2.0].

In the packages config when the user installs A-1.0, they will get B-1.0 as well.
If the user chooses though, they can update package B to 2.0 and NuGet restore will still work.

Comment: But being an author of my own package I am at the same time the user of the dependent package. I am forced to specify its exact version in `packages.config`, but can set the range in `.nuspec` file.

Comment: Exactly and that's how it should be. 

There's a difference between compatible versions and actually installed or resolved versions.

Comment: In that sense `PackageReference` more consistent. I declare floating dependency like `3.*` and `nuget restore` brings me the latest version within `3` release. If `SemVer` convention is followed, there should not be breaking changes. It's a kind of unification of `nuspec` and `config`

Comment: I wouldn't call it a unification.
The nuspec is the package declaring it's own dependencies. It's package author side. It's guidance of how the package should be used, or what it needs to work properly.

The package reference is the user declaring what he wants to get. 
NuGet tries to do what it thinks is best for the user, but it's very easy to get into a situation where there's a conflict between declarations for different packages. 

So NuGet has a strategy of resolving these : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/dependency-resolution